# Change background color of the ScrollViewer in a DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, scrollbar

in my Silverlight Application all controls must be completely transparent so that the Background Image can be seen. In my actual work I need to show data in a DataGrid. After reading the answer to the question [Change background color of Datagrid Header in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325654/change-background-color-of-datagrid-header-in-silverlight) that solved the problem of the non transparent Header of the DataGrid I still have the problem that the spare in the Header of the ScrollViewer of the DataGrid will stay white, whatever style I apply to the ScrollViewer and the ScrollBar. Furthermore the horizontal ScrollBar stays white. Here are my actual styles for the ScrollBar and the ScrollViewer (eg in the Listbox this works like a charme).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollBarControlTemplate" TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid x:Name="Root">
            <Grid x:Name="HorizontalRoot">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Grid.Column="0" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonLineLeftStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Grid.Column="1" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonBlankStyle}" />
                <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="16" Style="{StaticResource ThumbHorizontalStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Grid.Column="3" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonBlankStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Grid.Column="4" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonLineRightStyle}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="VerticalRoot" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalSmallDecrease" Grid.Row="0" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonLineUpStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalLargeDecrease" Grid.Row="1" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonBlankStyle}" />
                <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="16" Style="{StaticResource ThumbVerticalStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalLargeIncrease" Grid.Row="3" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonBlankStyle}" />
                <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalSmallIncrease" Grid.Row="4" Interval="50" Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonLineDownStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle" TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarControlTemplate}" />
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" TargetType="ScrollBar" />
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle}" TargetType="ScrollViewer" />
```

I'm running out of ideas, maybe someone can help me!?

To give you a more clear idea of my problem, here is what it looks like at the moment:

[BothScrollBars](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/4087/bothscrollbars.jpg)